# Execute SSM documents using boto3 aws multi account support

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, ssm

I was implementing centralized multi-account patching with AWS Systems Manager Automation. When operating in the console and using the "Automations" section of the SSM, you can indeed point to multiple accounts assuming you have correct role passing set up. None of the other methods of running a document support this though, not maintenance windows, not document associations, none of them.

Could you help me with the method/function that can be used to trigger multi account deployment.